# Substitute string with placeholder values coming from JSON object

Tags: javascript, json

I have a string "Good $timeOfTheDay$, $name$"

$timeOfTheDay$ and $name$ are placeholders whose values are contained in a JSON object.

```
var content = { "timeOfTheDay" : "evening",
                "name" : "Jack",  
                "city" : "New York",  
                "age" : "25",  
              }
```

Want to substitute the placeholders in the string with the values from the JSON object. The resulting string would be: **"Good evening, Jack"**

Want to do this in javascript. This does not involve any interaction with the DOM.

I'm guessing the brute force way to do it would be via writing JS code to do the replace but is there a library or another way to do this?

Appreciate any ideas/help. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The extended solution using `String.split`, `String.replace`, `Array.map` and `Array.join` functions:

```
var content = {"timeOfTheDay" : "evening", "name" : "Jack", "city" : "New York", "age" : "25"},
    str = "Good $timeOfTheDay$, $name$", replaced = "";

var parts = str.split(/(\$\w+?\$)/g).map(function(v) {
    replaced = v.replace(/\$/g,"");
    return content[replaced] || replaced; 
});

console.log(parts.join(""));  // "Good evening, Jack"
```

Additional example:

```
...
str = "$name$ lives in $city$. He is $age$";
...
console.log(parts.join(""));  // "Jack lives in New York. He is 25"
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `String.prototype.replace` function

```js
var content = { "timeOfTheDay": "evening", "name": "Jack", "city": "New York", "age": "25", }

var str = "Good $timeOfTheDay$, $name$"

var result = str.replace('$timeOfTheDay$', content.timeOfTheDay)
                .replace('$name$', content.name);

document.write(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var content = { "timeOfTheDay" : "evening",
                "name" : "Jack",  
                "city" : "New York",  
                "age" : "25",  
              }
              
document.getElementById('greeting').placeholder = 'Good ' + content.timeOfTheDay + ', ' +content.name;
```

```html
<input id='greeting'>
```

Answer (score 0):

This library can be useful for replacing placeholder. This could also be used to recursively replace placeholders. 
https://github.com/tarangkhandelwal/substitutor.js

Ex:

> nameJson= {
>           "first":"John",
>           "last":"Doe"
>           }
>
> var fullName = substitutor('My name is {first} {last} ', nameJson);

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `${var}` convension:

```js
var content = {
  timeOfTheDay: 'evening',
  name: 'Jack',
  city: 'New York',
  age: '25'
};

var str = 'Good ${timeOfTheDay}, ${name}. I am from ${city}, ${age} years old';

var parts = str.split(/(\$\{\w+?})/g).map(function(v) {
  var replaced = v.replace(/\$\{(\w+?)}/g, '$1');
  return content[replaced] || v;
});

console.log(parts.join(''));
```

Output

```
Good evening, Jack. I am from New York, 25 years old
```

Answer (score 0):

Exported my solution into a handy function you can call with any string.

```
export function getValue(text, values) {
  return text.replace(/\$\w+\$/g, (match) => {
    const variable = match.slice(1, -1);
    return values[variable] || match;
  });
}
```

### Usage

```
var content = {
  timeOfTheDay: "evening",
  name: "Jack",
  city: "New York",
  age: "25",
};

const jsonString = "Good $timeOfDay$ $name$ from $city$"

getValue({ jsonString, {
  "timeOfDay": content.timeOfTheDay,
  "name": content.name,
  "city": content.city
  }
})
```

```
Result: "Good evening John from New York"
```